# Is it possible to acknowledge TCP packet manually?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am making application in c#. Here i want to acknowledge the TCP packets manually. (Means i want to create the Acknowledgement packet manually and send it back). Whether is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do that with http://www.winpcap.org/ libary known from the wireshark project.

Comment: @Dany - What are you really trying to do?  In any case, "raw sockets" might be what you are after, but I'm not sure if that would work. You could google for "NDIS driver" and catch raw ethernet frames.  YMMV.

Comment: Oh, and "Winsock LSP" is another thing to google for. And if you want to be annoyed by a talking head on a web page, go here: http://winsocklsp.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think, acknowledge is bottom layer, that you work on VisualStudio. So, you can't, i think.

Comment: Visual studio is irrelevant to this question. The question is about which API supports such low level access to packets, and I suspect lower level APIs such as "raw sockets" indeed support this in some form.